# How many invocations can I cast as a warlock per round?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, warlock, eldritch-invocations

Yesterday I created a warlock for a new underdark campaign we started. We all started at level 3 so I picked 3 invocations ( normally 2 but I traded 1 feat for 1 invocation). I picked walk unseen (invisibility), fell flight, and entropic warding.

I was wondering if it is possible to use both walk unseen and fell flight in a single round. Can I for instance do: go up 25 ft with fell flight, 15 ft forward and use walk unseen (my movement speed is 40ft due to the spry flaw I picked) in a single round or am I limited to 1 invocation per round?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] for further guidance. I made an edit to the post to try to clean it up but feel free to revert or further [edit] if you don't like some of the changes. I wasn't sure enough to edit this out but it appears that your last question "Also with the case of entropic warding, do I need to cast it on my self or is it a passive invocation which gets triggered automatically?" is different enough that it could be asked separately in a new question. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using an invocation is a standard action by default. So unless you have an ability that changes that (such as the Quicken Spell-Like Ability feat) or a source of extra standard actions (such as *celerity*), you can only use one per round.

However, for your specific example, *fell flight* has a 24-hour duration, and once you activate it, the flight speed it gives you becomes a part of your normal movement. So as long as you use *fell flight* before combat starts (which you should, there's very little reason to not have it active 24/7), you can do your flight as a move action and then still use *walk unseen* on the same turn. Additionally, *walk unseen* also has a 24-hour duration, so you could even have both of them already up and then do something else entirely with your standard action (but since *walk unseen* mimics *invisibility*, it still breaks when you attack).

Comment: Thanks! That cleared out a lot! I was not sure if at-will actions were considered standard actions or not. I will discuss with my DM to have my flight and invisibility active at all times then.

Comment: @UniQuadrion Just keep in mind that his point is not that they are always active, but that the duration of each ability is 24 hours. This can be important in cases such as dispelling, or if you do something that cancels your invisibility.